# Django + Forms: Dynamic choices for ChoiceField

Tags: django, forms

I'm trying to create a dynamic list of choices for the ChoiceField but I can't seem to call request.  Here's the code:

**The Error:**

```
AttributeError: 'CreationForm' object has no attribute 'request'
```

**Forms**

```
class FooForm(forms.Form):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(FooForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        bars = self.request.session['bars']
        foo_list = []
        for bar in bars:
            foo_list.append((bar['id'], bar['name']),)
        self.fields['foo'].choices = foo_list
    foo = forms.ChoiceField(choices=foo_list, required=True)
```

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Why not pass the choices in from the view when you instantiate the form?

e.g.

Form:

```
class FooForm(forms.Form):
    def __init__(self, foo_choices, *args, **kwargs):
        super(FooForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['foo'].choices = foo_choices

    foo = forms.ChoiceField(choices=(), required=True)
```

View:

```
... 
bars = request.session['bars']
foo_list = []
for bar in bars:
    foo_list.append((bar['id'], bar['name']),)
form = FooForm(foo_list)
...
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  I wanted to avoid separating the two operations, but it seems like there is no other way...

Comment: The problem with method is that when you call is_valid() on the form instance in another view there are no choices passed, so the is_valid() always returns False

Comment: How could we reuse FormView with this special Form? Normally FormView doesn't accept arguments when instanciating the Form... Do I have to write a custom specialization of FormView?

Answer (score 1):

To get deal with the validation on `is_valid()` action, i think this will work

```
class FooForm(forms.Form):
    def __init__(self, foo_choices, *args, **kwargs):
        self.base_fields['foo'].choices = foo_choices
        super(FooForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    foo = forms.ChoiceField(choices=(), required=True)
```

*The code above are untested*

Comment: I might be mistaken but wouldn't this override the class attribute base_fields? Meaning that this will modify the choices for the class and not for the instance?