# Too many values to unpack (expected 2) Django

Tags: python, django, forms, choicefield

I am creating a form that contains a `ChoiceField` to which I establish the values of choice by means of view.

According to Django documentation [ChoiceFields Choices](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/forms/fields/#django.forms.ChoiceField.choices) the election values must be:

> Either an iterable (e.g., a list or tuple) of 2-tuples to use as choices for this field, or a callable that returns such an iterable. This argument accepts the same formats as the choices argument to a model field.

When loading the view, I do not get any problem. But when I try to get the value of the `ChoiceField` after validating the form in the view I get an error `Too many values to unpack (expected 2)`.

I do not know if I am wrongly adding the values of choice in the `ChoiceField`. Although I suppose if it were this the view would not load either. What am I doing wrong ?

forms.py

```
class FormAffiliateReport(forms.Form):

...

referrals = forms.ChoiceField(choices=(), label='Choice Referral', widget=forms.Select(attrs={'class': 'form-control',}))

def __init__(self, referrals, *args, **kwargs):
    super(FormAffiliateReport, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    self.fields['referrals'].choices = referrals
```

views.py

```
def affiliate_report(request):
if request.session.has_key('affiliate_code'):
    affiliates = []
    affiliate_code = request.session['affiliate_code']
    affiliates = get_affiliates(affiliates, affiliate_code)
    affiliates.sort(key=lambda affiliate: affiliate.name.title())
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = FormAffiliateReport(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            referrals = form.data['referrals']
            return render(request, 'blog/affiliate_report.html', {"affiliate_code": affiliate_code, "form": form})
    else:
        choices = ()
        for affiliate in affiliates:
            choices = choices + ((str(affiliate.code), affiliate.name),)
        form = FormAffiliateReport(choices)

    return render(request, 'blog/affiliate_report.html', {"affiliate_code": affiliate_code, "form": form})
else:
    return redirect('home')
```

Traceback

```
File "C:\Users\pc\Environments\company\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 41, in inner
response = get_response(request)
File "C:\Users\pc\Environments\company\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 187, in _get_response
response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
File "C:\Users\pc\Environments\company\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 185, in _get_response
response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "C:\Users\pc\Projects\company\blog\views.py", line 224, in affiliate_report
return render(request, 'blog/affiliate_report.html', {"affiliate_code": affiliate_code, "form": form})
File "C:\Users\pc\Environments\company\lib\site-packages\django\shortcuts.py", line 30, in render
content = loader.render_to_string(template_name, context, request, using=using)
File "C:\Users\pc\Environments\company\lib\site-packages\django\template\loader.py", line 68, in render_to_string
return template.render(context, request)
File "C:\Users\pc\Environments\company\lib\site-packages\django\template\backends\django.py", line 66, in render
return self.template.render(context)
File "C:\Users\pc\Environments\company\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 207, in render
return self._render(context)
File "C:\Users\pc\Environments\company\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 199, in _render
return self.nodelist.render(context)
File "C:\Users\pc\Environments\company\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 990, in render
bit = node.render_annotated(context)
File "C:\Users\pc\Environments\company\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 957, in render_annotated
return self.render(context)
File "C:\Users\pc\Environments\company\lib\site-packages\django\template\defaulttags.py", line 216, in render
nodelist.append(node.render_annotated(context))
File "C:\Users\pc\Environments\company\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 957, in render_annotated
return self.render(context)
File "C:\Users\pc\Environments\company\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 1046, in render
return render_value_in_context(output, context)
File "C:\Users\pc\Environments\company\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 1024, in render_value_in_context
value = force_text(value)
File "C:\Users\pc\Environments\company\lib\site-packages\django\utils\encoding.py", line 76, in force_text
s = six.text_type(s)
File "C:\Users\pc\Environments\company\lib\site-packages\django\utils\html.py", line 385, in <lambda>
klass.__str__ = lambda self: mark_safe(klass_str(self))
File "C:\Users\pc\Environments\company\lib\site-packages\django\forms\boundfield.py", line 41, in __str__
return self.as_widget()
File "C:\Users\pc\Environments\company\lib\site-packages\django\forms\boundfield.py", line 94, in as_widget
attrs = self.build_widget_attrs(attrs, widget)
File "C:\Users\pc\Environments\company\lib\site-packages\django\forms\boundfield.py", line 250, in build_widget_attrs
if widget.use_required_attribute(self.initial) and self.field.required and self.form.use_required_attribute:
File "C:\Users\pc\Environments\company\lib\site-packages\django\forms\widgets.py", line 690, in use_required_attribute
return use_required_attribute and first_choice is not None and self._choice_has_empty_value(first_choice)
File "C:\Users\pc\Environments\company\lib\site-packages\django\forms\widgets.py", line 673, in _choice_has_empty_value
value, _ = choice
ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)
```

Comment: Can you please show the *full* traceback?

Comment: This line looks wrong: `self.fields['referrals'].choices = referrals`. You're trying to pass all of the `POST` data into the choice field.

Comment: @RobinZigmond So in what way should I modify that line? I was being guided by this response, to send the options to the ChoiceField [Dynamic choices for ChoiceField](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22255759/django-forms-dynamic-choices-for-choicefield)

Comment: @alejandrodxf that answer only works because they instantiate the form in the view by passing in an explicit list of choices, each of which is a 2-tuple. At no point in that example is `request.POST` passed in to the form's constructor. It looks like this construction was needed because the OP there wanted the list of choices to depend on what was in the user's session. You don't say in your question what you want the choices to be, but in most cases it's a constant list, so you can just define it in your `Form` class.

Comment: Although you still could do something like this and still accept `request.POST` as an argument - you just have to have another argument in the constructor. As I said, the best solution depends on what you need the choices to be (in particular whether they're dynamic or static), which you don't say.

Comment: @RobinZigmond The options are dynamic, so I do not define them in the form class. As I understand you then I must add another argument here
def __init __ (self, referrals, * args, ** kwargs):?

Comment: Having thought about it a bit more and looked up what I've done in similar situations, you're probably better off using a key-word argument. So you define your choices in the view and call it, say, `choices`, then instantiate the form as `form = form = FormAffiliateReport(request.POST, choices=choices)`, and in the constructor saying `choices = kwargs.pop("choices")` before the call to `super`, and then `self.fields['referrals'].choices = choices`. (Of course you don't need to call it `choices`, any name would work.) Let me know if this works and I'll make it into an answer if it does.

Comment: @RobinZigmond  This has worked for me. Thank you very much for your help and patience.

Comment: Thanks, no problem :) I've formally made this into an answer, and would appreciate it if you accepted it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To formalise what I'd already put in the comments:

The issue in the OP is that the `referrals` argument to the `Form`'s constructor was taking on the entirety of the `POST` data when the form was instantiated as `form = FormAffiliateReport(request.POST)`. What was needed was to use a keyword argument to represent the dynamically changing choices.

So, in the view, do this:

```
choices = ... # some computation, specific to the OP's needs
form = FormAffiliateReport(request.POST, choices=choices)
```

and in the `Form` class:

```
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    choices = kwargs.pop("choices")
    super(FormAffiliateReport, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    self.fields['referrals'].choices = choices
```