# cannot unpack non-iterable datetime.date object

Tags: python, django

I'm building a booking form, and want to allow users to pick a date of booking from available dates in the next 60 days.

I get the next 60 days by:

```
base = datetime.date.today()
date_list = [base + datetime.timedelta(days=x) for x in range(60)]
```

Then I subtract already booked dates which are stored in the db:

```
bookings = list(Booking.objects.all())
primarykeys = []
unav = []

for b in bookings:
    primarykeys.append(b.pk)

for p in primarykeys:
    unav.append(Booking.objects.get(pk=p).booking_date)

for date in unav:
    if date in date_list:
        date_list.remove(date)
```

Then I change the result into tuple for the forms(not sure if this is right?):`

```
date_list = tuple(date_list)
```

Then I pass it into the form field as such:

```
booking_date = forms.ChoiceField(choices=date_list, required=True)
```

This gives me an error of `cannot unpack non-iterable datetime.date object`

And now am I stumped...how can I do this? I have a feeling i'm on the complete wrong path.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The docs for [Django Form fields](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/forms/fields/#django.forms.ChoiceField.choices) says the following:

> **choices**
>
> Either an iterable of 2-tuples to use as choices for this field, or a callable that returns such an iterable. This argument accepts the
>   same formats as the choices argument to a model field. See the model
>   field reference documentation on choices for more details. If the
>   argument is a callable, it is evaluated each time the field’s form is
>   initialized. Defaults to an empty list.

It looks like what you're passing is a tuple in this format:

```
(date object, date object, ...)
```

But you need to be passing something like a list of 2-tuples, with the first element of each tuple being the value stored for each choice, and the second element being the value displayed to the user in the form:

```
[(date_object, date_string), (date_object, date_string), ...)
```

Change your code to the following and see if that works for you:

```py
base = datetime.date.today()
date_set = set([base + datetime.timedelta(days=x) for x in range(60)])
booking_dates = set(Booking.objects.all().values_list('booking_date', flat=True))
valid_dates = date_set - booking_dates

date_choices = sorted([(valid_date, valid_date.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')) for valid_date in valid_dates], 
                      key=lambda x: x[0])
```

I've used sets to make it simpler to ensure unique values and subtract the two from each other without multiple `for` loops. You can use `values_list` with `flat=True` to get all the existing booking dates, then create a list of 2-tuples `date_choices`, with the actual datetime object as the value and display a string representation in whatever format you choose using `strftime`.

Then the dates are sorted using `sorted` by date ascending based on the first key, since using sets will mess up the sort order.

Then take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22255759/9374673) to see how you can pass these choices into the form from your view, as I don't think it's good to try to dynamically set the choices when defining the Form class itself.

Comment: Thanks man, what a fantastic comprehensive answer, can you tell me why it's not a good idea to set the choice in forms.py? What about if i set the choice outside of the Form class itself but in the same file?

Comment: It really has to do with when that code runs to actually set the choices. I presume you'd want to set it whenever the form is initialized. Maybe you can override the form's `__init__` method and put the code in there, so that you set the choices when it's instantiated, but then I feel like you might as well do what that top answer does and pass the choices in from the view as a parameter that the form expects when it's created. You can play around with it and see if it works for you. I've found that with Django there are usually multiple ways of doing something, each with its own advantages.

Comment: @alvo That answer I linked has the particular requirement that some information has to come from the request, so to make that accessible in the form, you have to pass it in somehow from the view that handles that `request` object. Since you're just getting **all** `Booking.booking_date` values, I think it would probably work to have that code in the form's `__init__` and set the choices for that field each time the form is created, since those dates will change over time. Maybe try that first and see if it works.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the additional information, will definitely look at adding the code to the forms __init__!