# Django forms Choicefield parameter session key

Tags: python, django, forms, session

I am working on a project which bases operations on the session_key parameter.

I would like to fetch data from the database and add the variables into a choicefield in forms.
Using the **ModelChoiceField(queryset=..., empty_label="(Nothing)")** could be an option, but i still cant take in the session_key as a parameter to filter the queryset.

so my question, how can i fetch the session_key from the request in views and pass it to the queryset in the forms class?

Thx!

UPDATE:

FORM:

> class CreateChartForm(forms.Form):
> def **init**(self, var_list, *args, **kwargs):
> super(CreateChartForm, self).**init**(*args, **kwargs)
> self.fields['x'] = forms.ChoiceField(choices=tuple([(name, name) for name in var_list]))
> self.fields['y'] = forms.ChoiceField(choices=tuple([(name, name) for name in var_list]))

But now i cannot pass REQUEST.POST to the form...

**form = CreateChartForm(var_list=df.columns.to_list())**

Answer (score 0):

The terms you probably want to search are "Django"  and "dynamic ChoiceField".

I don't have an example to hand, but [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22255759/django-forms-dynamic-choices-for-choicefield) seems to have answers pretty much as I would have guessed.

Comment: You are totally right! I Updated my original question with the FORM and the initiation of the form in the Views file. Cant pass the request.POST now and therewith the form doesnt want to validate....

Answer (score 0):

Okay now i have been using the "trial and error" methods and a big selection of questions here on Stack.

IF you want to dynamically create choicefields from a django model without using the modelform you can get it via *args and *kwargs.

I modified my Form as below in FORMS.py:

```
class CreateChartForm(forms.Form):

def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(CreateChartForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    req, cols = args
    self.fields['x'] = forms.ChoiceField(choices=tuple([(name, name) for name in cols]))
    self.fields['y'] = forms.ChoiceField(choices=tuple([(name, name) for name in cols]))


CHART_CHOICES = (
    ("Linjediagram", "Linjediagram"),
    ("Stapeldiagram", "Stapeldiagram"),
    ("Korrelationsgraf", "Korrelationsgraf"),
    ("Kaka", "Kaka"),
)

chart = forms.ChoiceField(choices=CHART_CHOICES)
titel = forms.CharField(max_length=255)
```

Then i passed both the request.POST and the dataframe.columns.to_list() in the VIEWS.py file:

```
    form = CreateChartForm(request.POST, df.columns.to_list())
```

Now i have a form which can access dynamic variable names through a Pandas Dataframe and adding them to a drop down style choice field in a form :-)